# vector field as a projection of a constant vector field on an embedding space

Tags: differential-geometry

(Also asked in math overflow. So if you dont find it appropriate here, moderators please remove this.)
Suppose a tangent vector field is given on a planar curve and one asks the following question:
What is the condition on this tangent vector field that it comes from the ordinary Euclidean projection of a constant vector field defined on a planar 2 dimensional neighbourhood of this curve?
A simple necessary and sufficient condition is if one parallelly translates, in the usual Euclidean sense, each tangential vector of the given field to a common point on the plane, the tips of the translated vectors describe a circular arc. This can be easily proved by elementary Euclidean geometry.

My question is if it can be seen in a more matured way, I mean, in terms of parallelism, connection, covariant derivatives, in these languages. Specifically, what I am looking for is some specially defined connection with respect to which the covariant derivative of the given tangential field being zero implies, and is implied by, the field be a projection of a constant field in the embedding space.